# Which is the best frequent flyer program to join?

Tags: airlines, loyalty-programs

I am guessing it would be an airline in Star Alliance or One world based on the partner airline benefits. But which of these airlines would be better?

I choose United because it has quite a few partner airlines beyond the Star Alliance ones but I will be interested to hear your opinions.

Comment: Welcome to the Travel.SE. Please, be more specific in your questions. "Which is the best"-type of questions are very broad and subjective, so there is no right answer. Please, rephrase your question or it will be closed.

Comment: How often do you travel? Where do you tend to travel from and to? What class? Are you mostly after airmiles, upgrades, lounge access?

Answer (score 3):

It really depends on where you live and travel to. For example for me (I live in London) the best one would be [oneworld](/questions/tagged/oneworld), because it provides the most direct connections.